# Default or inherited {{sections}} Using Hogan in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hogan.js

When I call res.render is there a way to always use the same variables for sections? For example:

```
res.render('index', {
        layout: 'layouts/dashboard/slim',
        partials:{
          partial_one: "path/to/partial_one.hjs",
          partial_two: "path/to/partial_two.hjs"
        },
        title: 'Dashboard',
        section_one: foo,
        section_two: bar
      });
```

I would like res.render to always have the two sections to be associated with foo and bar, with out having to include them in the call every time. Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create customRender :

```
renderCustom('index', {
  layout: 'layouts/dashboard/slim',
  title: 'Dashboard',
  section_one: foo,
  section_two: bar
});

function renderCustom(name, object) {
  object.partials = {};
  object.partials.partial_one =  "path/to/partial_one.hjs";
  object.partials.partial_two =  "path/to/partial_two.hjs";

  res.render(name, object);
}
```

Or alternatively, you could hot patch the render function.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var render = res.render;
  res.render = function (view, locals, cb) {
    if (typeof locals == 'object') {
        locals.partials = {};
        locals.partials.partial_one = "path/to/partial_one.hjs";
        locals.partials.partial_two = "path/to/partial_two.hjs";
    }
      render.call(res, view, locals, cb);
};
  next();
});
```

Comment: Worked great.  I think you may have confused the partials with the sections though so just had to swap them around.  Ended up going with the hot patch option.  Thanks again!